# parse.com push messages with badge icon

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I just added parse.com api to my app and can not find a way to send push with my badge icon maybe its a error by me or error by parse.com but i added that correctly i am sure.
it sends push notifications but without my badge icon.
i added this meta too but nothing happend still no badge icon

```
<!-- replace @drawable/push_icon with your push icon identifier -->
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"    android:resource="@drawable/push_icon"/>
```

what could i miss? from here ? 
https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reading parse.com tutorial on this matter i realized that you should add the badge explicitly when you are pushing a Notification.

The message you send needs to look like this

```
{
 "aps":
  {
  "alert":{"action-loc-key": "Open","body": "Hello, world!" },
  "badge": 2
  }
}
```

And with my understanding without the "badge": 2 the badge is cleared.